# Books on logical fallacies

Tags: logic, reference-request

I'm interested in learning and understanding logical fallacies for better skills in debate and discussions and in hopes to improve critical thinking as well. Can you guys please recommend me some books (or audiobooks but not ebooks/pdfs/epubs etc.) on this? It'd be helpful if it has examples as well. :)

Comment: May I humbly suggest my proof-checking software with accompanying tutorial which is downloadable at my website http://www.dcproof.com While it doesn't dwell on logical fallacies as such, it can be used to learn the formal rules of logic that we normally use to construct all valid arguments and proofs.

Comment: Who needs books when you have the internet? :P http://yourlogicalfallacyis.com / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies / http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12728/complete-list-of-logical-fallacies

Comment: @stoicfury: Internet is never a substitute for a book. It never should be. For a person who is starting to learn a subject, a well organized material, put in well thought wording, in an engaging way with further readings, is essential. Which is what an author of a good book does and with Internet, it is left to learner to choose. Internet is learning things the hardway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A book with a detailed chapter [see Chapter 3] dedicated to *fallacies* is :

- Patrick Hurley, [A Concise Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1285196546).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will surely try this book. At the moment I found this [Book on logical fallacies by Bo Benett](http://www.amazon.com/Logically-Fallacious-Ultimate-Collection-Fallacies/dp/1456607529/) It serves as a dictionary for logical fallacies which is pretty nice for reference purposes but the book you suggested looks like a guide to logical and critical thinking, I will try that definitely. Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on the chart beneath at [/r/SocialEngineering](https://redd.it/71r0zr). Comments there also moot https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/, https://www.yourbias.is/.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*A rulebook for arguments* by Anthony Weston has a chapter on fallacies and subchapter with a list of fallacies; in this book, the author indicates another book with a bigger list of fallacies: *Logic and Contemporary Rhetoric* by Howard Kahane.

Another I know is *The art of being right: 38 ways to win an argument* by Arthur Schopenhauer, but I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Nonsense: A Handbook of Logical Fallacies - Robert Gula - this book is a good compilation of fallacies in simple but technically rigorous terms.